cv2.imshow() not working with Picamera2 library
I'm facing an issue with displaying images using imshow when capturing images with picamera2 on my Raspberry Pi. Here are the details:
Problem: After capturing an image using picamera2, I'm unable to display it using imshow from OpenCV or although matplotlib. The imshow window doesn't appear at all.
I am using:

Python Version: 3.11.22
Raspberry Pi Model: Raspberrypi5
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
picamera2 version: 0.3.18

Steps taken:

Verified picamera2 installation and dependencies.
Captured an image successfully using picamera2.
Tried to display the image using imshow from OpenCV, it works for opencv when only working with images and not videocapture in that case it returns error, but when using cv2.imshow with Picamera2 i didn't get anything.
Camera tested with hello_lib command and works well.

This is a minimalist program for test:
import cv2
from picamera2 import Picamera2
import time
def capture_frames():
   picam2 = Picamera2()
   picam2.start()
   while True:
      im = picam2.capture_array()
      print(im.shape)
      im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
      cv2.imshow("Face Attendance", im)
      cv2.waitKey(1)
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
capture_frames()

Has anyone encountered similar issues with imshow and picamera2? If so, could you please share your insights or solutions?
Any advice on how to troubleshoot or resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Where you print the image shape, also print image.dtype and image.max() and image.min() and tell us what it prints.

Technically you should convert RGB2BGR rather than BGR2RGB but actually the net effect is the same so you'll get away with it.

needs debugging details. [mre] may be helpful. figure out the shape and dtype
